# Google Data Studio custom charts

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, looker-studio

I need to use a Google Data Studio pivot table with conditional formatting, what it doesn't support out-of-the-box, hence I'm trying to code a custom table that does it. I reached this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/visualization/get-started), but can't find any documentation about how to change a bar chart to a table.

Answer (score 0):

Custom charts (Community Visualizations) are created using JavaScript. If you want to create your own table/pivot table viz, you will need to write JavaScript code for that. For example, you can use the [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table) library to render tables.