# How to load Google Charts library in Data Studio Visualizations without html code

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, google-visualization, looker-studio

I am trying to use the Google charts library, but cannot figure out how to "link" it.
I put in the first line of the js file:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
```

From the console I read that "google is not defined" (it is very clear what it means). My guess that this piece of code is missing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

but I cannot figure out how to load Google Charts without html code. Any help?
btw, I am new with JS. More experienced in python and C/C++.

came from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60423825/19884814